# Camel CXF: compressing response with CXFOutInterceptor throws classcast exception

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I have a service bundle where I want to compress a response by using CXF GZIPFeature. The bundle is deployed on JBoss Fuse(jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379). Camel route configuraion is:

```
<cxf:bus id="cxf" name ="cxf">
    <cxf:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPFeature">
            <property name="threshold">
                <value>1</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

<camel:camelContext ...>
    <camel:route id="test-server">
        <camel:to uri="cxfbean:servicebeans?bus=#cxf&amp;providers=#providers" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

But this throws classcast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPOutInterceptor$GZipThresholdOutputStream cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelDestination$CamelOutputStream.commitOutputMessage(CamelDestination.java:284)[204:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelDestination$CamelOutputStream.doClose(CamelDestination.java:296)[204:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:220)[164:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.0.redhat-610379]
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:241)[:1.7.0_67]
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:77)[164:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.0.redhat-610379]
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.close(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:102)[164:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.0.redhat-610379]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)[164:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.0.redhat-610379]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)[164:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.0.redhat-610379]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)[164:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.0.redhat-610379]
```

Is there a legal way to use CXF GZIPFeature in the route? I don't want to use Camel's DataFormat to gzip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using servicemix-camel-cxf and had nearly the same problem. In the end I decided to simply add this in route:

`<marshal>
    <gzip/>
</marshal>`

Check it out - maybe it will help you too.
But in that case you have to set `Content-Type: gzip` header.

Try to add

```
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <constant>gzip</constant></setHeader>
```

However for me it didn't help, so I added header in java code. =)